# Selenium c# click on element with no name or id

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Selenium c# how can I perform click on this element?

Class names are fixed will not be randomely generated

```
<div class="l61y9joe j8otv06s a1itoznt qwtvmjv2 kiex77na lgsfgr3h mcogi7i5 ih1xi9zn ippphs35 a53abz89">Create Post</div>
```

This is my c# code I am using.

```
webDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.facebook.com/Entertainment4vip/publishing_tools/");
webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[contains(text(),'Create Post')]"))
    .Click();
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xDQC.png)

screen shot of the button is also attached bellow

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the C# code you already tried. The expectation at StackOverflow is to provide a [repro] along with your question.

Comment: Select it by the class? Do you control the source code of this website? Is the class randomly generated (maybe in an attempt to prevent people from doing what you're doing)?

Comment: Also, are the classes listed in the `class` attribute random, or do they appear the same every time. Can you also add the HTML tags that exist above the `<div>` tag? Those would be considered the ancestor tags of the `<div>` tag.

Comment: why not find it by text?

Comment: webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[contains(.,'Create Post')]"))

I try this to find by text but it trough exception XPath can't find the element

Comment: @GregBurghardt This is Create post button on Facebook publishing tool doesn't look like it is random ATM but they change after a few days. Classes I have in last week are different than current ones.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include code. Code in comments is too hard to read.

Comment: @GregBurghardt I update my question and post my code sample

Comment: Please do not post images of code. Copy and paste the code into your question. You can format the code by highlighting those lines of text and clicking the form as code icon in the question editor.

Answer (score 0):

An xpath that would work is

```
"//div[contains(text(),'Create Post')]"
```

Full code:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
wait.Until(e => e.FindElement(By.XPath("//a/h3")))
    .click()
```

Or if the element you're looking for is in an iframe:

```
   driver.SwitchTo().Frame(driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("xpath_to_frame")));
   WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
   wait.Until(e => e.FindElement(By.XPath("//a/h3")))
       .click()
```

Comment: I am getting this exception here: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[contains(text(),'Create Post')]"}
  (Session info: chrome=87.0.4280.141)

Comment: you'll want to "wait" for the element explicitly. Will add code.

Comment: Iframe part help i realise after a long time it was wrapped in an iframe.

Comment: You might want to select this as the right answer then if the iframe was the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I manage to resolve this didn't realise div as wrapped inside an Iframe answer from @DMart help me. Thanks for your support everyone.